# Match two SQL database records using Python by a database column field (list of lists)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

I have a problem when I tried to compare two databases that I read using python. The problem is to write a proper

```html
for
```

cycle. Databases are read using:

```html
output_po = psql.read_frame(sql_po, conn)
output_stock = psql.read_frame(sql_stock, conn)
```

sql_po records:

```html
PO        PN       
FTP1     1111      
FTP2     2222
```

sql_stock records:

```html
PN    WHS    NAME
1111  VLN     A
1111  VLN     B
1111  ZRS     A
2222  DLN     Q
```

So the result i want to get is to get all sql_stock info based on sql_po info where Whs == 'VLN'. Result:

```html
PO      PN       WHS    NAME
FTP1   1111      VLN      A
FTP1   1111      VLN      B
```

I have tried using:

```html
    for index, row in sql_po.iterrows():

        if sql_stock[sql_stock['PN']==row['PN']].empty:
            send_email = 'F'
        else:
            if (sql_stock[sql_stock['Whs'] =='VLN'].any ):
               send_email = 'T'
```

But it gives all 3 records for PN 1111 from sql_stock as for 1111 there are 2 with Whs=vln and 1 with Whs=zrs. Could you guys help me solve that problem?

Comment: what query are you using to fill : sql_po (I might add that I know next to nothing about python but the problem you seem to be having is sql related and not so much python)

Comment: no, problem is python related, python shows good results when i print querry, but do not know how to take info line by line when we do have list of lists